# Android TV. How to implement getMainFragmentAdapter() method inside VerticalGridSupportFragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to integrate a VerticalGridSupportFragment() inside a BrowseSupportFragment() based on some of the Leanback examples.

On running the code below (partial snippet provided below) I get the exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fragment must implement MainFragmentAdapterProvider`

I'm struggling to understand how to implement the interface methods defined by MainFragmentAdapterProvider [i.e getMainFragmentAdapter()]. Could anyone provide insight surrounding this issue, or could you provide an example? I've tried to return the mRowsAdapter, however it was not of the correct type.

Any help would really be appreciated, thanks!

```
class MainFragmentByGroupFragment : BrowseSupportFragment() {

   override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate")
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        prepareBackgroundManager()

        mainFragmentRegistry.registerFragment(
            PageRow::class.java,
            PageRowFragmentFactory(mBackgroundManager)
        )

        setupUIElements()

        createRows()

        setupEventListeners()
    }

    private class PageRowFragmentFactory(backgroundManager: BackgroundManager) : BrowseSupportFragment.FragmentFactory<androidx.fragment.app.Fragment>() {

        override fun createFragment(rowObj: Any?): androidx.fragment.app.Fragment {
            val row = rowObj as Row
            return ChannelFragment()
        }
    }

}
```

```
class ChannelFragment : VerticalGridSupportFragment(), OnItemViewClickedListener, BrowseSupportFragment.MainFragmentAdapterProvider {

    private var mRowsAdapter: ArrayObjectAdapter? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mRowsAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(CardPresenter())
        setAdapter(mRowsAdapter)
        setOnItemViewClickedListener(this)
        createRows()
    }

    private fun createRows() {
        val gridPresenter = VerticalGridPresenter()
        gridPresenter.numberOfColumns = NUM_COLUMNS
        setGridPresenter(gridPresenter)
        setOnItemViewClickedListener(this)

        val list = MovieList.list

        for (i in 0 until 100) {

            mRowsAdapter!!.add(list[i % 5])
        }
    }

    override fun onItemClicked(
        itemViewHolder: Presenter.ViewHolder?, item: Any,
        rowViewHolder: RowPresenter.ViewHolder?, row: Row?
    ) {
    }

    override fun getMainFragmentAdapter(): BrowseSupportFragment.MainFragmentAdapter<*> {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    companion object {
        private const val NUM_COLUMNS = 5
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement getMainFragmentAdapter.
Add the following to ChannelFragment:

```
private val mMainFragmentAdapter: BrowseSupportFragment.MainFragmentAdapter<*> =
    object : BrowseSupportFragment.MainFragmentAdapter<Fragment?>(this) {
        override fun setEntranceTransitionState(state: Boolean) {
        }
    }
```

And return mMainFragmentAdapter in getMainFragmentAdapter:

```
override fun getMainFragmentAdapter(): BrowseSupportFragment.MainFragmentAdapter<*> {
    return mMainFragmentAdapter
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but dont worry, already fixed it